# Как выбрать записи за минуты?

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE r.status = rs.id
```

Как выбрать записи за минуты? Время лежит в поле `date_create` в формате `datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

В общем виде так:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE (r.status = rs.id) AND (date_create BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo)
```

где `DateFrom` и `DateTo` - значения `datetime`.
Если надо за последние 30 минут, можно проще:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE (r.status = rs.id) AND (date_create BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE() AND GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@ksladkov](/users/8018/ksladkov)](/users/8018/ksladkov), смеешься? Это делается намного проще:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE r.status = rs.id
AND date_create >= ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE)
```

---

Мог опечататься, набирал с телефона.

Comment: @johniek_comp Действительно, смешно :)
Каюсь, у тебя лучше.